# Amazon Location Services - searchPlaceIndexForSuggestions is not a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-location-service

I'm using Amazon Location Services for a mapping project that I'm working on and I want to implement autocomplete using `searchPlaceIndexForSuggestions` as outlined at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/search-place-index-autocomplete.html
and documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location-places/latest/APIReference/API_SearchPlaceIndexForSuggestions.html

I'm able to call `location.searchPlaceIndexForText` and `location.searchPlaceIndexForPosition` just fine and get the expected responses, but when I call `location.searchPlaceIndexForSuggestions` with relevant parameters I get `Uncaught TypeError: location.searchPlaceIndexForSuggestions is not a function`.

My declaration for `location` is

```
const location = new AWS.Location({credentials, region: AWS.config.region});
```

The relevant IAM role has the following in its policy:

```
"Action": [
                "geo:GetMapGlyphs",
                "geo:GetMapSprites",
                "geo:GetMapStyleDescriptor",
                "geo:SearchPlaceIndex*",
                "geo:GetMapTile"
            ],
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in the policy, calling the function incorrectly, declaring location incorrectly, or what. Any ideas or assistance would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your IAM policy seems fine. There are a couple of things I'd suggest:

- Take a look at [a blog](https://dev.to/mepa1363/how-to-add-a-location-search-widget-to-your-web-app-using-amazon-location-service-17jb) I wrote or [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfjDidhCuPA) I published on how to add a location search with autocomplete to your web app using AWS Amplify (Amplify Geo).
- Take a look at the following code snippet, which uses the [AWS SDK V3 Location Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-location/index.html)

```js
import {
  LocationClient,
  SearchPlaceIndexForSuggestionsCommand
} from '@aws-sdk/client-location';

const client = new LocationClient({
    credentials: YOUR_AWS_CREDENTIALS,
    region: YOUR_AWS_REGION
  });

const command = new SearchPlaceIndexForSuggestionsCommand({ Text: YOUR_SEARCH_TERM, IndexName: YOUR_PLACE_INDEX_NAME });
const response = await client.send(command)
console.log(response);
```

Hope this helps.